# How to get Epoch day and time in C for even different time zone?

Tags: c, linux

Here is my code in C where I am trying to get the current epoch day and time. However, it seems to be wrong? What am I missing in the logic here?
This is a legacy code and I am not sure why we need to adjust the offset.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SECS_IN_DAY (60 * 60 * 24)
static void GetEpochs()
{
    const int SECS_IN_MINUTE = 60;
    const int MIN_IN_HOUR = 60;
    const int SECS_IN_HOUR = SECS_IN_MINUTE * MIN_IN_HOUR;


    int offset; /* difference (+/-) between local and UTC time in seconds */
    time_t currentTime = time(NULL); /* current time in seconds */
    time_t adjustedTime; /* current time adjusted for timezone */

    struct tm* locTime = localtime(&currentTime);
    int localHour = locTime->tm_hour;
    int localMin = locTime->tm_min;

    struct tm* gmTime = gmtime(&currentTime);
    int gmHour = gmTime->tm_hour;
    int gmMin = gmTime->tm_min;

    /* create difference between local and gm time in (+/-) seconds */
    offset = ((localHour * SECS_IN_HOUR) + (localMin * SECS_IN_MINUTE)) - ((gmHour * SECS_IN_HOUR) + (gmMin * SECS_IN_MINUTE));

    /* adjust for wrapping over/under a day */


    if (offset > SECS_IN_DAY/2)
        offset = offset - SECS_IN_DAY;
    else if (offset < -(SECS_IN_DAY/2))
        offset = offset + SECS_IN_DAY;

    /* Create the adjusted time */ 
    adjustedTime = currentTime + offset;


    printf("Epoch Hour = %ld\r\n",adjustedTime/((15 * 60)));

    printf("Epoch Day = %ld\r\n",adjustedTime/(((60 * 60 * 24))));
}

void main()
{
  GetEpochs();

}
```

Comment: Are you aware about [`tzset()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tzset.3.html)? I must admit that I've no experience with this - just remembered that it exists.

Comment: Better post your question on [CodeReview StackEx](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: What do you mean with _Epoch day?_

Answer (score 0):

The timezone used for the various functions defined in the `time.h` header is determined by the `TZ` environment variable.

Using the `localtime()` function without touching the `TZ` env, will by default use your operating system's timezone. More precisely, it will use whichever file you've symlinked to `/etc/localtime` from the the system timezone directory on UNIX systems (which is `/usr/share/zoneinfo` on mine). Personally I don't know what other OS's do.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    // print date and time in your local timezone
    struct tm* t1 = localtime( &(time_t){time(NULL)} );
    printf("%s", asctime(t1));

    // print date and time in UTC
    setenv("TZ", "UTC", 1);
    struct tm* t2 = localtime( &(time_t){time(NULL)} );
    printf("%s", asctime(t2));

    // print date and time reading from the timezone file
    setenv("TZ", ":Europe/London", 1);
    struct tm* t3 = localtime( &(time_t){time(NULL)} );
    printf("%s", asctime(t3));

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program will look like this:

```
Tue May  8 09:49:42 2018
Tue May  8 07:49:42 2018
Tue May  8 08:49:42 2018
```

The file I talk about in the third example is relative to the system timezone directory, `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London` in this case.

You can read more about the `TZ` env and the ways you can adjust it in the `tzset()` [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tzset).